# Call Android Email intent from Unity script

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a feedback button in unity game, if the user clicks on it then it should launch an default email app with subject, email address filled already. I have done this in Android app but how to call it from unity?

Are there any other better approaches for feedback other than this?

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is plugin. You don't need plugin for this.

You can simply send email with:

```
void sendEmail(string toEmail, string emailSubject, string emailBody)
{
    emailSubject = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(emailSubject);
    emailBody = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(emailSubject);
    Application.OpenURL("mailto:" + toEmail + "?subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + emailBody);
}
```

To send, call:

```
sendEmail("example@example.com", "Test", "This is a text\r\nAnother test\r\nAnd another text");
```

This will work on PC, Android and iOS. I don't know for Mac.

Now if you still want to use Android API's, you still don't need to make a plugin for this. You can use `AndroidJavaObject` and write your email code with Android API.

```
private static void SendMail(string subject, string body, bool useHTML)
{
    using (var intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent"))
    {
        // intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        using (var intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND")))
        {
            // Setting text type
            if (useHTML)
                // intent.setType("text/html");
                intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/html");
            else
                // intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "message/rfc822");

            // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);

            // Setting emailBody
            if (useHTML)
            {
                // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailBody));
                using (var html = new AndroidJavaClass("android.text.Html"))
                {
                    var htmlBody = html.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromHtml", body);
                    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), htmlBody);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), body);
            }
            using (var unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                using (var currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                {
                    currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to call it `SendMail("test", "Message", false);`. You can improve it and add more features to it. This last example was lifted from [here](http://developers-club.com/posts/175509/).

Comment: I need the customer to enter the email body. Rest everything is prepopulated.

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah The first function in my answer will do it. You get the body from `InputField` then pass it in to the sendEmail function. You then put send email and subject yourself in the function. What's hard to do here? I even gave an example on how to use this.

Answer (score 4):

@Programmer's (native-method) answer is correct; but when the user is prompted to select an app to send the email, there's a good chance the user will have the possibility to select apps other than e-mail apps; e.g. WhatsApp. We don't want this to happen. As stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email) the way we could ensure that only e-mail apps will be shown to the user, is to use `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` and `intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")`.

```
private void SendMail(string subject, string body)
{
    using (var intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent"))
    {
        // intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        using (var intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SENDTO")))
        {
            //intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            var uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
            var uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "mailto:");
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setData", uriObject);

            // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
            //intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_EMAIL"), "youremail@abc.xyz");
            string[] email = { "youremail@abc.xyz" };
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_EMAIL"), email);

            // Setting emailBody
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), body);
            using (var unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                using (var currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                {
                    currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `youremail@abc.xyz` with the e-mail you intend to send the e-mail to.

The question is, why do all this hassle instead of simply sending the e-mail like stated below:

```
void sendEmail(string toEmail, string emailSubject, string emailBody)
{
    emailSubject = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(emailSubject);
    emailBody = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(emailSubject);
    Application.OpenURL("mailto:" + toEmail + "?subject=" + emailSubject + 
"&body=" + emailBody);
}
```

You might want to add HTML or some non-Latin text (e.g. Japanese, Arabic) to your e-mail's body. using `System.Uri.EscapeUriString` is going to mess that up. In that case, the native method will be your method of choice.

Answer (score 0):

On Button click you have to call:

```
  public void OpenActivity()
    {
        var androidJC = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        var jo = androidJC.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        // Accessing the class to call a static method on it
        var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.xyz.abc.StartActivity");
        // Calling a Call method to which the current activity is passed
        jc.CallStatic("Call", jo);
    }

}
```

Replace it by your activity and package name

> var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.xyz.abc.StartActivity");